# генерация разметки Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

привет есть код.

```
var list = jQuery('<ul />').attr('class', 'list-ul');
$.each(data, function (key, val) 
{
    list.append('<li class="list-li">' + val.City + '</li>');
}
```

То есть хочу сделать

```
<ul class="list-ul">
 <li class="list-li"></li>
 ......
 <li class="list-li"></li>
</ul>
```

но не создается

Элементы добавляются если указать элемент

```
$.each(data, function (key, val) 

    {
        $("#data").append('<li class="list-li">' + val.City + '</li>');
    }
```

Comment: добавьте после цикла `$("body").append(list);`

Comment: спасибо помогло